# How to yield an argument

Tags: ruby, yield

This method reproduces the `map` method in order to obtain a deeper understanding of how `yield` works.

I researched `yield` but I couldn't figure out why it is taking the iteration element as an argument.

I know `yield` retrieves a block, but what *exactly* is being yielded here and why does it take an argument?

The code below is correct:

```
def my_map(array)

  new_array = []
  array.each do |element|
    new_array << yield(element)
  end

  new_array
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I tried to research `yield` a great deal but I can't figure out why in this case it is taking the iteration element as an argument.

`yield` doesn't take an argument. The block does. `yield` yields the value to the block.

> I know `yield` retrieves a block,

No, it yields control (and values) to the block.

> but what *exactly* is being yielded here and why does it take an argument?

The object referenced by `element` is yielded to the block, along with the flow of control.

Answer (score 1):

`yield` doesn't 'retrieve a block", it yields (potentially with a value, like in this case) *to* a block, and "returns" the value returned by said block.

It's "taking" the iteration element because `my_map` expects a block that receives a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `yield` is the same thing as calling `block.call`. So `yield` calls the block with your argument. That's it.

(You can think of a block as a mini-method.)

However in your method, you're not explicitly saying it accepts a block (`def my_map(array, &block)`), but it implicitly does that.

So your implementation, just rewritten slightly, is equivalent to:

```
def my_map(array, &block)  # added &block

  new_array = []
  array.each do |element|
    new_array << block.call(element)   # changed for block.call
  end

  new_array
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yield(element)` passes `element` to the block provided to the `my_map` method.

```
my_map([1,2,3]) {|element| element*2}
```

The block is receiving `element` as input which you passed from `yield(element)`.

Consider another example to help make it clear:

```
def simple_yield(arg)
  yield(arg)
end
```

Now if you do:

```
simple_yield(10){|x| puts x} #=> 10
simple_yield(){|x| puts x} #=>nil
```

`yield(arg)` yields the argument to the block given to the method.

Comment: Please use correct punctuation/grammar when asking or answering. Stack Overflow isn't a discussion group or a forum where those don't matter. Instead it's a reference book, like an encyclopedia or cookbook.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take care of this next time onwards.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass any parametr to the block through yield method, than the parameter will have nil value which might cause an error according to what you are doing in the block passed to the method that is using yield.

```
def my_map(array)
  new_array = []

  array.each do |element|
    new_array << yield
  end

  new_array
end

my_map([1,2]) { |x| x } #=> [nil, nil]
my_map([1,2]) { |x| x + 1 } # will end up with undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```